# Laravel application fails to complete migration - New install - How to fix database connection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

I set up a new application for a customer and got up to php artisan migrate and I get the classic error:

> SQLSTATE HY000 2002 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I scoured all the config files and tried all combinations of database but I sure it's not that. It seems to be between the built-in web server and the database. I configured MySQL as follows:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=mcc_majestic 
DB_USERNAME=root 
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I'm running Laravel 8.23.1 and PHP 8. The newly installed operating system is Windows 10 Pro to support Docker later. The firewall is not the issue. Has anyone ended up in this position and what did you change to fix it? I am stuck until this issue is resolved. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So the database server is running the localhosf? Did you check again the password for the root account?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Laravel issue.

Make sure your local server is up & running.